# Remove wide characters, Perl

Tags: perl, unicode

I am trying to send a String via a socket using a perl program. I am getting an error saying that the text contains a wide character, and the socket can't deal with that. Is there a way to either:

A: Turn on wide characters through the socket

or

B: Remove all wide characters from a string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It means you're trying to send text over a handle, yet handles can only communicate bytes. You need to serialise the text into bytes. Specifically, you want to *encode* the text. You can use [Encode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Encode)'s `encode` function

```
print $sock encode('some_encoding', $text);
```

or you can instruct the socket to do it for you

```
binmode $sock, ':encoding(some_encoding)';  # once
print $sock $text;
```

Replace `some_encoding` with the encoding expected by the other end of the socket (e.g. `UTF-8`).

Answer (score 0):

[PerlIO](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html) and [binmode](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) might help you solve your problems